# Inside `geth` how could I convert abi object into a string?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, abi, string, console

Inside `geth` how could I convert abi object into a string? I want to convert it into string to apply `str.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '');` to remove new lines and make it more compact.

```
myContractCompiled.Array.info.abiDefinition
```

returns the abi of the contract as:

```
[{
    constant: true,
    inputs: [{
        name: "id",
        type: "string"
    }, {
        name: "index",
        type: "uint256"
    }],
    name: "get_length",
    outputs: [{
        name: "",
        type: "uint256"
    }],
    payable: false,
    type: "function"
}, 
...
{
    inputs: [],
    payable: false,
    type: "constructor"
}]
```

But I am facing with following error when I try to convert abi object into string:

```
> myContractCompiled.Array.info.abiDefinition.toString()
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> JSON.stringify(myContractCompiled.Array.info.abiDefinition)
"[{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"test_callstack\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"int256\"}],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"ownerOnly\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"owner\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"transferOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"payable\":false,\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"type\":\"constructor\"}]"
```

See also: [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)